# Object attributes dependencies in Ruby Module?

Tags: ruby, class, module

I have a class called **ProductImage** which have an attribute called `'src'`. That attribute stores the URL of the **ProductImage**.

So, I want to create a module used to manipulate images, so I can manipulate **ProductImages**, **LogoImages** and so on.

Here is what I have so far, but I am confused:

```
module ImageManipulation
  # Crop method
  def crop
    # First we need to have a MiniMagick instance so we can crop.
    @minimagick = MiniMagick::Image.open(self.src) # Is this correct? 
  end
end
```

What confuses me is that if we rely on `self.src`, which is an attribute of the Class that is mixing the module, what if this module is mixed in a class which objects don't respond to `self.src`? How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What confuses me is that if we rely on `self.src`, which is an attribute of the Class that is mixing the module, what if this module is mixed in a class which objects don't respond to `self.src`?

Then you will get a `NoMethodError` which tells the user of your module exactly what is going wrong.

> How should I approach this?

You don't. The language will take care of this for you by raising a `NoMethodError`.

Well, okay, you shouldn't take care of this *in code*. But you *should* document your mixin's *protocol*, something like this:

> Objects that mix in `ImageManipulation` must respond to `src` with an instance of `URI` representing the source of the image to be manipulated.

Note: `self` is the implied receiver in Ruby, you don't need to explicitly specify it.